# Tailwind CSS (PostCSS Plugin) with Next.js 10.0.3 gives Javascript heap out of memory error in dev environment

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css, postcss

To replicate the issue you can use this example and run in the dev environment.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss

The above example have also very high memory usage in dev environment which is not so common for next js applications.

I have tried the combination of different versions of tailwindcss and Next.js but the issue persists.
PS: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 (If this would help in any way).

Comment: Did you fined a solution for this, I'm also on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I have set up Gulp for Tailwindcss and pm2 to restart when memory exceeds 1024 MB. I know this setup is very annoying but I didn't found any other solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I too encountered this error `FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` when I integrated Tailwind(2.2.2) on my NextJS (10.2) project.

Some github-issue discussions on Memory Leaks points to the use of optimized `<Image/>` component of NextJs.
So I've temporarily reverted back to `img` tag and it's stable so far.

No an ideal solution but give it a try.

Also I've disabled `JIT` mode of Tailwind in development.

Github Discussions [#1](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/23637) [#2](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/23189)